# linux + how to convert disk DEV name to humane reading

Tags: hard-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux, udev, dev

we get from site remote machine the files under `/var/log/sa/*`

and we copy all them on our local machine under `/var/tmp/sa/*`

so when we run `sar -f /var/tmp/sa/sa14 -d` on our local machine

we get the following.

```
11:20:01 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
11:30:01 PM    dev8-0     27.15    178.46    219.40     14.65      0.07      2.49      1.35      3.68
11:30:01 PM   dev8-16    686.51 124630.29  82215.26    301.30      2.71      3.95      0.51     35.11
11:30:01 PM  dev253-0      0.69      2.35     23.39     37.08      0.00      1.07      0.51      0.04
11:30:01 PM  dev253-1     35.91    175.71    111.61      8.00      0.11      2.94      1.02      3.65
11:30:01 PM  dev253-2      0.87      0.00     84.41     96.91      0.00      0.02      0.02      0.00
11:30:01 PM  dev253-3      0.04      0.41      0.00     10.78      0.00      9.04      3.35      0.01
11:40:01 PM    dev8-0     24.28    225.11    272.16     20.48      0.07      3.08      1.82      4.42
11:40:01 PM   dev8-16    541.94  87031.10  81678.03    311.31      2.83      5.22      0.43     23.15
11:40:01 PM  dev253-0      1.06     17.58     26.25     41.16      0.00      1.30      0.71      0.08
11:40:01 PM  dev253-1     31.60    188.22     64.57      8.00      0.12      3.76      1.37      4.34
11:40:01 PM  dev253-2      1.77     19.42    181.35    113.23      0.00      0.41      0.14      0.02
11:40:01 PM  dev253-3      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
11:50:01 PM    dev8-0     35.95    168.49    283.24     12.56      0.09      2.54      0.97      3.50
11:50:01 PM   dev8-16    791.67 152374.13  78838.34    292.06      3.97      5.02      0.53     41.98
11:50:01 PM  dev253-0      1.23      7.69     29.48     30.27      0.00      1.05      0.51      0.06
11:50:01 PM  dev253-1     41.96    158.93    176.79      8.00      0.12      2.95      0.82      3.45
11:50:01 PM  dev253-2      0.85      1.28     76.96     92.07      0.00      0.11      0.09      0.01
11:50:01 PM  dev253-3      0.03      0.44      0.00     13.20      0.00      8.65      2.45      0.01
Average:       dev8-0     62.85    397.57    422.69     13.05      0.16      2.55      0.94      5.88
Average:      dev8-16    922.78 120491.42 172502.93    317.51     10.66     11.55      0.43     39.63
Average:     dev253-0      1.12     22.95     24.89     42.84      0.00      1.98      0.97      0.11
Average:     dev253-1     79.89    355.61    283.48      8.00      0.24      2.97      0.72      5.76
Average:     dev253-2      1.33     18.69    114.25     99.99      0.00      0.83      0.36      0.05
Average:     dev253-3      0.02      0.31      0.04     16.05      0.00     11.35      3.55      0.01
```

do you know about available bash/per/other script in network that we can run on site remote machine in order to convert the disks devises as `dev253-3` to `sdb` for example? , and so on

Comment: If you want pretty device names, why are you not using `sar -p -d` ?

Answer (score 0):

For pretty device names, use the `-p` parameter of the
[sar command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sar.1.html) :

```
 -p, --pretty
          Make reports easier to read by a human.  This option may
          be especially useful when displaying e.g., network
          interfaces or block devices statistics.
```

For creating a translation table, the simplest would be to run the command
[lsblk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html).
Example output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda      8:0    0   20G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0   20G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   20G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   20G  0 part
└─sdb9   8:25   0    8M  0 part
```